# How do I set up a recurring charge where the amount fluctuates

Tags: c#, paypal, asp.net-web-api2

I need to use our Paypal account to handle recurring charges (we presently just do one-time charges for our online store). What I think I want (feel free to let me know if this is not optimum) is:

1. We pass a customer from our website to Paypal's website, with the expected monthly charge and the maximum monthly charge. At this point they are registering for a 1 month free trial.
2. Paypal validates the credit card and returns a token to us for upcoming charges.
3. After 1 month, and every month after that, we use the token to charge their card. We pass the token and the charge amount.
4. We get back success or an error code, with the error code giving us the specific problem.

First off, is this the best way to do this? I think it's very safe because that token is only good for our company charging the card and we hold no card info. So even if a hacker gets the token - all they can do is have that person send us money, which will then be reversed.

Second, how do I do this? We're programming in C# using ASP.NET Web API2 for the REST server component and Sencha/javascript for the web pages. Is there any example code for this? Both for the handoff to/return from the paypal page for entering the credit card info and for the code in our server to make the monthly charges.

thanks - dave

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Integrate Paypal for month charges that varies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368902/how-to-integrate-paypal-for-month-charges-that-varies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to this direct from paypal and am reposting it here as it fully answers the question:

> "First off, is this the best way to do this?"
>
> What you're looking to do is a product called "Reference
>   Transactions". With your business model I believe this would be the
>   best fit for your needs. I do want to mention there is an approval
>   process, so you'll want to contact our Business Support team sooner
>   rather than later to ensure when you're done testing you're ready to
>   go live.
>
> "Second, how do I do this?"
>
> Here's where the documentation comes in:
>
> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/
>
> This page provides instructions on the redirect to PayPal to set up
>   the Billing Agreement, then walks through running Reference
>   Transactions for future purchases.
>
> You can find our SDK's here (I've linked the Merchant SDK directly for
>   you):
>
> http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#merchant
>
> Here is our API explorer to see working examples of our API's:
>
> https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/PayPalAPIs